# Batch For Variables Printing Registry CSV

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop, registry, printers

When querying the below via cmd

```
REG QUERY "HKCU\Printers\Connections"
```

The output is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections\,,xxx-SD-KDP11,Colour
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections\,,xxx-SD-KDP11,Mono
```

However when running the Batch file containing code below

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
echo ============================
echo Network Printers ...
if exist network_printers.txt del network_printers.txt
if exist network_printers2.txt del network_printers2.txt

set reg_keys=
set blank=
set printers_network_paths=
set printers_network_types=

REG QUERY "HKCU\Printers\Connections" > network_printers.txt

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('type network_printers.txt') do set network_printers_init=!network_printers_init! %%A
echo !network_printers_init! > network_printers2.txt
echo !network_printers_init!
pause

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=, skip=4" %%a in ('network_printers2.txt') do (
  set reg_keys = !reg_keys! %%a
)

for /f "tokens=2,* delims=, skip=4" %%a in ('type network_printers2.txt') do (
  set blank = !blank! %%b
)

for /f "tokens=3,* delims=, skip=4" %%a in ('type network_printers2.txt') do (
  set printers_network_names = !printers_network_names! %%c
)

for /f "tokens=4,* delims=, skip=4" %%a in ('type network_printers2.txt') do (
  set printers_network_types = !printers_network_types! %%d
)

echo reg_keys: !reg_keys!
echo blank: !blank!
echo Network Printers paths: !printers_network_names!
echo Network Printers types: !printers_network_types!

echo Network Printers paths: !printers_network_names! >> %file%
echo Network Printers types: !printers_network_types! >> %file%
pause
```

the .csv file produced has nothing for !printers_network_names! and !printers_network_types!
Also the `echo` lines show nothing being stored in the last 4 variables.

Please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `for /f` loop, `"skip=4"` means skip 4 lines, but `network_printers2.txt` only contains one line.

There's some other stuff that can be improved.  Mainly, when you set a variable in batch scripting, you should `set "varname=string"`, quoted like that and with no spaces surrounding the `=`.  You can also do what you need without the intermediate text files and the useless use of `type`.

I'm not entirely certain what you want the end result to be, but it looks like you're making your script a whole lot more complicated than it needs to be.

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
echo ============================
echo Network Printers ...

for /f "tokens=2* delims=," %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Printers\Connections"') do (
    set "printers_network_names=!printers_network_names! %%A"
    set "printers_network_types=!printers_network_types! %%B"
)

echo Network printer paths: !printers_network_names!
echo Network printer types: !printers_network_types!
```

Result:

```
============================
Network Printers ...
Network printer paths:  xxx-SD-KDP11 xxx-SD-KDP11
Network printer types:  Colour Mono
```

Comment: Thank you. I was over-complicating it as you mention. Yes I did think that the `skip` option was for skipping tokens instead of lines, where the latter is correct.

Comment: Also how would I stip out all spaces in between the values - eg in `xxx-SD-KDP11 xxx-SD-KDP11` there is a space. How would you remove the space(s) in a `for` loop and replace with a single `|` ?